# ContextMenu in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I have a custom context menu in a datagrid. The context menu only works on when the selected record is still a textblock (non clicked) and on the first part of the record.

When I have clicked the record so it becomes a textbox, I can not use the context menu.

I now have figured out how to get this same context menu in the textbox, but when I click the items they do not work. As there as commands behind them.

How can I get the commands working?

Code for the custom context menu:

```
<support:CustomDataGrid.ContextMenu>
                            <custom:CustomContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                                <custom:CustomMenuItem Header="Show hex editor" Command="{Binding HexEditCommand}" InputGestureText="F8" />
                                <Separator />
                                <custom:CustomMenuItem Header="Append record" Command="{Binding AppendCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Insert" />
                                <custom:CustomMenuItem Header="Duplicate record" Command="{Binding DuplicateCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+Insert" />
                                <custom:CustomMenuItem Header="Delete record" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Delete" />
                            </custom:CustomContextMenu>
                        </support:CustomDataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Code for the textbox

```
<support:CustomDataGrid.EditingElementStyle>

                            <Style x:Name="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Reference ContextMenu}"/>
                                
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </support:CustomDataGrid.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: Did you try to define `custom:CustomContextMenu` as resource and then reference it using `{StaticResource key}` in the `TextBox` style? And how is `CustomDataGrid` and `CustomContextMenu` defined?

Comment: @mm8 I tried indeed as a resource, same issue then. The contextmenu is defined within the datagrid. The datagrid is just a datagrid. Not sure what you mean by how they are defined

Comment: What same issue? What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: @mm8 When I have it as a resource (just like the reference), the commands still dont work on the textbox style. It shows the menu but the commands do not work. But in the rest of the application / datagrid, the contextmenu works fine with commands.

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Are your commands available within the DataGrids DataContext? If not, you may want to use a binding proxy to access them.

Comment: @tabina Thats what I did indeed! A binding proxy works.